# OpenShift Online proxy port

Tags: openshift

Is there any workaround to lack of proxy port in OpenShift Online?

Why I need it? I've got three application gears. All of them run JBoss. One of them run additionaly MySql.
I need to make three ports (3306, 5445, 5455 - mysql and HornetQ) from gear with MySQL available to other gears (HornetQ to one and MySQL to another). Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a scalable application then you can access MySQL gear from other applications. Lets suppose you create a scalable application using JBoss and MySQL then OpenShift would install MySQL and JBoss on separate gears.This would allow other applications to access the MySQL database.

Comment: And do you know anything about accessing HornetQ inside JBoss (5445, 5455)? I don't have separate addresses/ports for that even in scalable application.